# STI brake shifters for cantilever brakes?

Tags: brakes, gears, brifters

I have a Jamis Aurora 2016:

[Jamis Aurora](https://www.evanscycles.com/jamis-aurora-2016-touring-bike-EV245097)

I'd quite like to convert it to have brake lever gear shifters (the shifters are on the end of the handlebar drops which I don't really like). But will they work with cantilever brakes?

Does anyone have experience of doing this? Is it a lot of hassle?

[image: From Jamis website]

Comment: Half the road bikes out there have cantis and brifters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they will work with most STI levers. Cantilevers and road calipers use the same cable pull. If you were ever to convert from cantilever to linear pull (v-brakes) then you would have to be more careful in matching them up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that replacement shifter/brake lever units are compatible with both the cantilever brakes *and* your derailleurs.

Tektro does not seem to make the 992 cantis your Jamis has anymore but I found a couple of online stores that claim they are comparable with STI road style levers.

Your Jamis has Shimano Tiagra/Sora derailleurs so you need Shimano shift levers. Matching Tiagra Shift levers would obviously work well.

Switching out levers is relatively straightforward. There are plenty of guides on line that will help you onstal and connect the new levers (The Park Tool Company YouTube channel is my favorite). The difficult part is that you will have to remove the bar tape to get the old levers off and new shift levers on. Replacing bar tape is tricky of you have not done it before.

Comment: Any Shimano 3x9 brifter will work. Also, Microshift branded ones will too. Finding the Shimano brifters might be a tricky part; Tiagra hasn't had a 3x9 in a few years, but the st-r3030 sora shifters should be a bit easier to find.